# In Project Orleans, is there any interceptor or filter like IOnGrainActivation and IOnGrainDeactivation?

Tags: orleans

For monitoring purposes, I need to log and measure every grain call (already available through [Grain Call Filters](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/grains/interceptors.html)), but also every grain activation/deactivation to have Grain Type counters, also for auto-scaling purposes.

I haven't found any global hooks besides Incomming and Outgoing grain call filters

[image: Image showing main extension methods for ISiloBuilder]

Is there any way to get into the lifecycle of Grains in a global manner, besides the Incomming and Outgoing call filters?

Comment: did you look at the existing telemetry? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/monitoring/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can using a feature in orleans called life-cycle participation which is available for grains and silos as well.

You should check out the [documentation site](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/grains/grain_lifecycle.html)